# `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch` requires to deactivate venv

Tags: ros, python-venv

I have a project with `venv` that works just fine, but when we need to run `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch` it will result in the error below unless we `deactivate` venv.

> process[rosbridge_websocket-2]: started with pid [10182]
>   process[rosapi-3]: started with pid [10183]
>   Failed to load Python extension for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be available.
>   Failed to load Python extension for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be available.
>   registered capabilities (classes):
>    - 
>    - 
>    - 
>    - 
>    - 
>    - 
>    - 
>    - 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rosbridge_server/rosbridge_websocket", line 44, in 
>       from rosbridge_server import RosbridgeWebSocket, ClientManager
>     File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbridge_server/**init**.py", line 4, in 
>       from .udp_handler import RosbridgeUdpSocket,RosbridgeUdpFactory
>     File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbridge_server/udp_handler.py", line 6, in 
>       from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol,Factory
>   ImportError: No module named 'twisted'

I am assuming this is because there's no module named `twisted` installed in the virtual environment but it is installed on my computer. Following this hypothesis, this means that making `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch` work would require to install all the dependencies that it needs in venv? How would one go to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but what version of python are you targeting with venv? I suspect it's a python 3.x, and if so, you have to setup for it. 
As you suspect, you're missing packages, this should be a good start (from [here](https://medium.com/@beta_b0t/how-to-setup-ros-with-python-3-44a69ca36674)), adjusting the commands to suit your venv.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-yaml
sudo pip3 install rospkg catkin_pkg
```

For more details, see the new ros wiki pages: http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3/IdentifyDependencies

Comment: If you identify what was needed, dependency wise, please post your steps for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

just make sure the version of python you are using in venv and the environment where those packages are installed is same, if thats not the case, then you probably need to correct the python paths.

Mostly when you are running something in venv, the interpreter will only look inside that virtual environment, so when i face that issue, i just stopped using venv for ros and exported the pythonpaths or any ros module if they are installed for python3. distribution.

Comment: I will mostly agree with this: virtualenvs are the best & proper way to do python, and they really suck with ros.